# Mongodb kafka connector: Can't extract id value from mongodb document to set as message key

Tags: mongodb, apache-kafka-connect, mongodb-kafka-connector

I'm new to kafka connect and I'm trying to use the mongodb source connector to send a kafka message after a document has been inserted. I have configured the connector as shown here:

```
{
  "name": "new-items-source",
  "config": {
    "name": "new-items-source",
    "connector.class": "com.mongodb.kafka.connect.MongoSourceConnector",
    "tasks.max": "1",
    "connection.uri": "mongodb://mongo1:27017",
    "database": "store",
    "collection": "items",
    "topic.prefix": "new_items",
    "publish.full.document.only": "true",
    "pipeline": "[{\"$match\": {\"operationType\": \"insert\"}}, {\"$project\": {\"fullDocument.bar\": 0, \"fullDocument._class\": 0, \"fullDocument.foo\": 0 } } ]",
    "transforms": "extractField",
    "transforms.extractField.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ExtractField$Key",
    "transforms.extractField.field": "$oid",
    "key.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://schemaregistry0:8585",
    "key.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
    "value.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://schemaregistry0:8585",
    "value.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
    "value.converter.schemas.enable": "true",
    "key.converter.schemas.enable": "true",
    "output.schema.value": "{\"type\": \"record\", \"name\": \"NewItemMessage\", \"namespace\": \"com.acme.store.adapters.out.kafka.avro\", \"fields\": [{\"name\": \"author\", \"type\": \"string\"}, {\"name\": \"_id\", \"type\": {\"type\": \"record\", \"name\": \"_id\", \"fields\": [{\"name\": \"oid\", \"type\": \"string\"}] } }, {\"name\": \"state\", \"type\": \"string\"}, {\"name\": \"text\", \"type\": \"string\"}] }",
    "output.format.key": "schema",
    "output.format.value": "schema",
    "output.json.formatter": "com.mongodb.kafka.connect.source.json.formatter.ExtendedJson",
    "output.schema.key": "{\"name\":\"KeySchema\",\"type\":\"record\",\"namespace\":\"com.acme.store.adapters.out.kafka.avro\",\"fields\":[{\"name\":\"fullDocument\",\"type\":{\"name\":\"fullDocument\",\"type\":\"record\",\"fields\":[{\"name\":\"_id\",\"type\":\"string\"}]}}]}",
    "errors.log.include.messages": "true",
    "errors.log.enable": "true"
  }
}
```

The transformation "extractField" is throwing following exception:

```
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: Schema type of struct but value was of type: object_id : Exception creating Source record for: Key={"_id": {"_data": "826419AE5E000000012B022C0100296E5A10046E7448252E594A93A4E029549626D02846645F696400646419AE5ED7FA7C2635DDCD5A0004"}, "operationType": "insert", "clusterTime": {"$timestamp": {"t": 1679404638, "i": 1}}, "wallTime": {"$date": "2023-03-21T13:17:18.396Z"}, "fullDocument": {"_id": {"$oid": "6419ae5ed7fa7c2635ddcd5a"}, "text": "My test", "author": "8abd2c6a-ad52-4583-a139-46572c7177ae", "state": "NEW"}, "ns": {"db": "twitter", "coll": "tweets"}, "documentKey": {"_id": {"$oid": "6419ae5ed7fa7c2635ddcd5a"}}} Value={"_id": {"$oid": "6419ae5ed7fa7c2635ddcd5a"}, "text": "My test", "author": "8abd2c6a-ad52-4583-a139-46572c7177ae", "state": "NEW"} at com.mongodb.kafka.connect.source.StartedMongoSourceTask.createSourceRecord(StartedMongoSourceTask.java:329)
```

Supposing that I have following document inserted:

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "6418d9a8375a166c657abcd4"
  },
  "text": "My Test",
  "author": "8abd2c6a-ad52-4583-a139-46572c7177ae",
  "foo": {
    "$numberLong": "0"
  },
  "bar": {
    "$numberLong": "0"
  },
  "state": "NEW",
  "_class": "com.acme.store.adapters.out.db.model.ItemEntity"
}
```

My goal is to extract the document ID (_id.$oid) and set this value as the key of the message. The key should just be a String representing the ID e.g.

Key:

```
"6418d9a8375a166c657abcd4"
```

Payload:

```
{
   "author": "8abd2c6a-ad52-4583-a139-46572c7177ae",
   "text": "My Test",
   "state": "NEW"
}
```

Does anybody have a hint or can help?

Comment: What happens when you use `"transforms.extractField.field": "_id"`?

Comment: It throws an exception as well.
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: Schema type of struct but value was of type: object_id : Exception creating Source record for: Key={"_id": {"_data": "826419AE5E000000012B022C0100296E5A10046E7448252E594A93A4E029549626D02846645F696400646419AE5ED7FA7C2635DDCD5A0004"}, "operationType": "insert", "clusterTime": {"$timestamp": {"t": 1679404638, "i": 1}}, "wallTime": {"$date": "2023-03-21T13:17:18.396Z"}, "fullDocument": {"_id": {"$oid": "6419ae5ed7fa7c2635ddcd5a"}, "text": "My test", "author": "8abd2c6a-ad52-4583-a139-46572c7177ae", "state": "NEW"}, ..